# Netgear WPS A6100 USB adapter not recognized

Tags: wireless, usb

I'm having the same issues as a lot of others.  Been through the other responses but can't seem to find the complete solution.

A6100 USB Network adapter.
Ubuntu - 20.4.1

Won't recognize usb.  have onboard 2.4g usb 5.0

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: What "same" issues you are having?

Comment: Ubuntu version - 20.04.1

Comment: issue .. os won't recognize usb network adapter.